# Prevent AjustPan from hiding actionbar/toolbar

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm working on messaging app. On Conversation activity i need to put Banner on the bottom of the screen under `EditText` as shown in the picture

[image]

But I want when the softkeyboard is visible the Banner ad whel move under the softkeyboard. On this problem i used `AdjustPan`. And it works! It hides the banner ad when the softkeyboard is visible. But the `ActionBar/Toolbar` hides. 
[image]

I already tried using `AjustResize`. This will prevent `Actionbar/Toolbar` from hiding when softkeyboard is visible. But this will also cause the banner ad to show above the softkeyboard. That is what i don't like.

I show an app that used banner ad under `EditText` but when softkeyboard is visible the banner ads disappear.

Comment: Hey! did you manage to find a solution to this. Its a real pain that the toolbar is hidden with `adjustPan` :(